# How does the blockchain verify new assets?

Tags: blockchain

how to verify new assets in a blockchain? For example: in order to participate in blockchain transactions, a member must first claim to have an asset that the network has not seen before, how would the network verify this claim? I've read a bunch of papers, but they're too bitcoin centric, which is that there are centralized institutions that issue block assets to members in exchange for real world currencies. And the non-bitcoin-centric mechanism seems to just assume that the new asset is inalienably verified, so just hash it directly with a timestamp as a new block. There doesn't seem to be any verification process. Is it incumbent on the application to determine a specialized verification algorithm? Am I just completely missing something? Please any response is appreciated.

Comment: Please post in an appropriate forum

Comment: @KaranShah There is no appropriate forum for blockchain discussion. Its a generic algorithm, irrespective of bitcoin and stackoverflow is more suitable than bitcoinstackexchange to discuss the same.

Comment: @Kang I think you need to read this http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129598/348614

Comment: @KaranShah Thanks Karan, I went through it and blockchain still qualifies under stackoverflow as "a computer algorithm" .. Could you be more specific if I am missing something?

Answer (score 0):

To track assets using the blockchain you create your own token and create a owner which can then assign people the asset using contracts or manually. If you are talking about currency then you either need to work and mine it or buy.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is the application's and mostly the user's responsibility. A real world asset cannot be pegged to a digital asset, blockchain or not, without a central authority enforcing such a peg.